# URL Rewrite in IIS

Tags: iis-7, url-rewriting

Whenever a request

```
http://localhost:9000/Content/PDF/ABC.pdf
```

comes (in IIS), i want URL rewrite module to process that request and redirect it to

```
http://localhost:9000/User/GetPdf
```

so that my controller and action methods are invoked and my code gets executed before a pdf file is shown to end user.

Here User is UserController and GetPdf is an ActionMethod in my application.

Can any body tell me steps to create this URL rewrite.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As a side note i found ISAPI_Rewrite really usefull. It will let you use .htaccess files in ISS without changing them at all. more info at http://www.helicontech.com/isapi_rewrite/

Comment: thanks dragon. but i dont have authority to add new plugin to my production server IIS. My Production server IIS have URL Rewrite module installed. I need to use that itself. Can u help further.??

Comment: Sorry don't know how to use the URL rewrite module in IIS.

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you are using IIS 7.x and you have installed [URL Rewrite 2.0 module](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=7435).

In your application's **web.config** file, add a `<rewrite>` element similar to:

```
<system.webServer>
   <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="PDF Rewrite">
          <match url="Content/PDF/([\w-]+)\.pdf" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="User/GetPdf/{R:1}" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

The `([\w-]+)` portion of `url="Content/PDF/([\w-]+)**\.pdf"` will "capture" the name of the PDF ("**ABC**" in your example) without the file extension.  The `{R:1}` portion of `<action type="Rewrite" url="User/GetPdf/{R:1}" logRewrittenUrl="true" />` will then insert the captured string.  The net result is that:

```
http://localhost:9000/Content/PDF/ABC.pdf
```

becomes:

```
http://localhost:9000/User/GetPDF/ABC
```

I am assuming that you will need to pass in the name of the PDF to your Action method, so if you implement the standard routing pattern `{Controller}/{Action}/{id}`, then the `id` will be set to "**ABC**".

The best introduction to the URL Rewrite module that I have found is actually the [URL Rewrite 1.1 configuration reference](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference).  Even though it is for v.1.1 rather than 2.0, it provides a better overview than the [v.2.0 Configuration Reference](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-20-configuration-reference).  It is worth reading from the start.  In particular, one must understand the “*Accessing URL Parts from a Rewrite Rule*” section.

To debug the URL Rewrite module, you can use the IIS 7.x "Failed Request Tracing," which, contrary to its name, can be used to trace successful as well as failed requests.  This [www.iis.net entry](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules) illustrates how to configure this and amount of detailed debugging information that is available.

Also note that the `logRewrittenUrl="true"` attribute means that the rewritten URL will be logged to the standard IIS log *instead of* the original URL.  (It can't be used to log both the original and the rewritten URL--- you can only get one or the other.)